# no such table: users [SQL: INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (?)] sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError)

Tags: sqlite, flask, migrate

**tablename** = 'users' not recognized by IDE I feel there is some issue with my below attached code

```
from puppycompanyblog import db
from flask_login import UserMixin


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    # Creating a table
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    # attributes table columns
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"UserName: {self.username}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `db.create_all()` first then you can add user into your table, currently there is no such table in your database.

Here is a useful code snippet to add a flask cli command `flask initdb` into your project, you can create or drop the database with the command before you run your application.

```
import click

@app.cli.command()
@click.option('--drop', is_flag=True, help='Create after drop')
def initdb(drop):
    '''Initialize database'''
    if drop:
        click.confirm('This operation will delete the database, do you want to continue', abort=True)
        db.drop_all()
        click.echo('Database dropped.')
    db.create_all()
    click.echo('Database Initialized.')
```